# Cannot add together different variables, even though values have changed

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

So I'm REALLY new to coding, so I'm learning as I go. I'm doing an assignment for a course, where I have to create a party booking program for a company. The idea is simple, just selected some different options, add them up, and calculate the costs. I have labels that will change and display the integer that the variable is set to, and they work perfectly which would tell me that the variables themselves are indeed getting changed.

However, once I try to add the variables together, it doesn't work.

```
public partial class AdultPayment : Form
{
    public static int ConvertNumberAdult = Convert.ToInt32(Adult.numberAdult);
    public static int MealCost = Adult.mealPrice*ConvertNumberAdult;
    private static int PrivateRoomCost;
    public static int TotalCost = MealCost + CalculateWine + PrivateRoomCost;        
    public static string DisplayNumberAdult = Convert.ToString(Adult.numberAdult);

    private static int CalculateWine { get; set; } = ConvertNumberAdult / 6 * 15;



    public AdultPayment()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        lblAdultConfirmName.Text = Adult.adultContactName;
        lblAdultConfirmNumber.Text = Adult.adultContactNumber;
        lblAdultConfirmDate.Text = Adult.adultDate;
        lblAdultConfirmTime.Text = Adult.adultTime;
        lblConfirmNumberOfAdult.Text = Adult.numberAdult.ToString();
        lblMealCostTotal.Text = "£"+ MealCost.ToString();
        lblCostTotal.Text = "£" + TotalCost.ToString();

        if (Adult.adultPrivateRoom == true)
        {
            PrivateRoomCost = 40;
            lblAdultConfirmPrivateRoom.Text = "Yes";
            lblPrivateRoomTotal.Text = "£"+ PrivateRoomCost;
        }
        else
        {
            PrivateRoomCost = 0;
            lblAdultConfirmPrivateRoom.Text = "No";
            lblPrivateRoomTotal.Text = "N/A";                
        }

        if(Adult.menuOption == true)
        {
            lblConfirmMenu.Text = "2 Courses for £15 each";
        }
        if(Adult.menuOption == false)
        {
            lblConfirmMenu.Text = "3 Courses for £18 each";
        }
        
        if (Adult.addWine == false) 
        {
            CalculateWine = 0;
            lblConfirmWineAdded.Text = "No";
            lblWineTotal.Text = "N/A";
        }
        
        else
        {
            lblConfirmWineAdded.Text = "Yes";
            lblWineTotal.Text = "£"+ CalculateWine.ToString();
        }

        lblCostTotal.Text = "£" + TotalCost.ToString();

    }

}
```

I have a different form, that allows the users to select their preferences, which works just as I need it to.
The variable that is supposed to add the other variables together is

```
public static int TotalCost = MealCost + CalculateWine + PrivateRoomCost;
```

I genuinely am so confused now, and because I'm so new to this I don't know how else to word it in order to find anything on the internet

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens exactly?

Comment: ok, welcome to StackOverflow. The first thing that you need to understand is that there is something called the "initialization" of a variable. If this happens on class level like in your case: `public static int TotalCost = MealCost + CalculateWine + PrivateRoomCost;` then this code is ran only once! when the variable or the type AdultPayment is accessed the first time! and never again. So you cannot expect that this calculation is performed ever again

Comment: Sorry! Where it is supposed to display the 'Total Cost' variable, it will only display the value of 'MealCost' and wont add 'MealCost', 'CalculateWine' and 'PrivateRoom' together

Comment: I could tell you that you could easily solve your wrong calculation results by adding a `>` making the line: `public static int TotalCost => MealCost + CalculateWine + PrivateRoomCost;` and it will work. But that would only confuse you even more. Because it is a higher level concept. And you clearly should work on the basics

Comment: It's because you're declaring it as a static variable. Please follow the comment of @MongZhu.

Comment: you need to make a method: `private int CalculateTotalCost(int MealCost, int CalculateWine, int PrivateRoomCost)` inside this method calculate the sum and use `return` to return the result. Then you need to call this method passing all 3 values into it.

Comment: we see only the constructor of your GUI Form. So there is no possibility for a user to take action. I could not even tell you where you should call this method. You would need some sort of a handler. Button-Click handler for example, because it is a method! So that the code can be actively and repeatedly executed. This is important. The declaration code of variables on class level cannot be used to perform any calculations

Comment: So youre saying that I would have to have another event that would allow it to do the extra calculation? would i still have to declare the variables at the start in the same place, then under a button_click method, i would have to do the calculation?

Comment: "another event that would allow it to do the extra calculation?"  in a way ' yes ' . the event is for the user to elicit an action in your program. "would i still have to declare the variables at the start in the same place" => Yes, otherwise you cannot use them for saving values temporarily. But the calculations are partly useless, they have to be performed at runtime. "then under a button_click method, i would have to do the calculation? " => Yes again